# How to make stmt_fetch turn result into array in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting so frustrated with this. I am trying to make an array containing the values of a column using mysqli. Right now when i echo what is returned it is printing nothing. I have tried so many things i can not figure this out.

```
<?php 
class Database {

    public $dbHost = '';
    public $dbUser = '';
    public $dbPass = '';
    public $dbName = '';

    public $db;

    public function __construct(){ 
        $this->dbConnect();
    }

    public function dbConnect(){

        $this->db = new mysqli($this->dbHost, $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass, $this->dbName);

        /* check connection */
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }else{
            echo 'connection made';
        }
    }

    public function q($sql){
        $query = $sql;
        self::preparedStatement($query);
    }

    public function preparedStatement($query){
        $i= 0; //index
        $result = array();

        if ($stmt = $this->db->prepare($query)){ 

            /* execute statement */
            if($stmt->execute()) {
                $stmt->bind_result($name);
                while($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $result[0] = $name;
                }
            } else
                echo "error";

            /* close statement */
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct(){}

}


### Test code

$db = new Database();
$res = $db->q("SELECT name FROM test");
echo $res[0];

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, remove the `0` in your `while` loop. You want the values to be stored in an array one after the other, what you're doing is always overwriting the first value in the array, and you need to store the value you get from `fetch()` in a temporary array.

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   $result[] = $row['name'];
}
```

second, you need your `q()` function to return some value, so change the last statement to

```
return self::preparedStatement($query);
```

Please spend some time Googling about this and looking at examples of how other people are doing it.

Comment: Sorry, i have been googling and i had put the 0 in just testing and didn't revert it back before i posted. my issue was not returning in my q() function. thank you so much